# slack app not responding to direct message

Tags: slack, slack-api

I want my app to respond to direct messages, but its not posting a reply and I can't find anywhere in the docs how to do it. This is what I have tried:

```
@app.event("app_mention")
def event_test(body, say, logger):
    logger.info(body)
    say("What's up?")

@app.event('message')
def respond_message(message, say):
    say("Hello there.")

@app.message('knock knock')
def respond_message(message, say):
    say("Hello there.")
```

It responds to @app mention, but doesn't respond to direct message...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you confirm that your app have required scopes to listen to 'message' event ?

Required scopes for 'message' event:

```
    channels:history
    groups:history
    im:history
    mpim:history
```

Here are the details:

https://api.slack.com/events/message

**Updating my answer for future use:**

https://api.slack.com/apis/connections/events-api

***Capturing events requires :***

1. Assign required scope for event
2. Subscribe to event

Answer (score 3):

I figured it out ~ in addition of adding the required scopes, you also have to toggle settings in the App Configuration -> Event Subscriptions tab... Docs could use some improvement tbh.

[image]

Comment: Could you perhaps let me know what part of the documentation you found to be unclear? I'm assuming you're referring to this (https://api.slack.com/apis/connections/events-api)?

Answer (score 0):

The above answers are correct

Also in addition to above, if it is a private channel then you would also need the following permission :

message.groups

It can be added from `Add bot user event` under event subscriptions.